# How to efficiently calculate the inverse of the overlap matrix?

Tags: matrix-elements, algorithms

Now, we consider a non-orthonormal basis:
$$\mathcal{S}_N=\{|\alpha\rangle,a^\dagger|\alpha\rangle,a^{\dagger 2}|\alpha\rangle,\ldots,a^{\dagger N}|\alpha\rangle\},$$
where $|\alpha\rangle$ is the coherent state and $a$ is the annihilation operator of bosonic mode.

Then, we assume $|\phi_m\rangle=a^{\dagger m}|\alpha\rangle\in\mathcal{S}_N$, and define the overlap matrix $S$ with the matrix elements:
$$S_{n,m}=\langle\phi_n|\phi_m\rangle, \text{where}\quad n,m\in[0,N].$$

In general, the problem of calculating the overlap matrix $S$ is simple, but its inverse matrix is not easy.

Finally, even if we can't obtain the analytical expression about the inverse matrix, I also want to obtain it efficiently in Matlab or Python. I want to explain why we can't correctly obtain its inverse matrix in the program. Firstly, when $|\alpha|\gg1$, the matrix $S$ becomes an ill-matrix, so we can't correctly obtain its inverse matrix, i.e., $S^{-1}S\neq I$, or the error is huge when we use the inverse matrix to do matrix multiplication. Secondly, we also choose a symbolic language to solve it, but the price greatly increases the computation time of matrix multiplication and addition. Finally, I especially want to find a suitable algorithm to solve it, and the analytical expression is secondary because sometimes I need to replace $|\alpha\rangle$ with $[|\alpha\rangle\pm|-\alpha\rangle]$ in my basis.

Comment: Have you done a web search for relevant papers ?  I had a quick glance and there seems to be papers on this.  [scicomp.se] might be a better source of info, as we don't generally do computational problems here.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine No, can you provide this information? Thanks.

Comment: We don't do web searches for other people here.  It's considered a minimum that people do basic research of their own (like that) before asking a question, with a view to focusing on some smaller issue or a conceptual issue.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I have tried many methods and also obtained some results in analytical calculation. I just can't efficiently solve it in program.